# How to put a Floating action button on all screens in Android

Tags: android, button, action, floating, floating-action-button

I have a requirement to put a floating action button on all screens of the application. I don't define all layout files, instead there any way I can generate dynamically and visible on all screens of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it's possible.
You could create one activity and multiple fragments with the current layout:

```
FrameLayout
-Framelayout container
-Your floating button
```

Then replace fragments in your container layout :).

You have to handle the floating button events in your activity.